# How can I publish a container in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

There is some icons just after container name in Google Tag Manager, see image. but neither are clickable. As it has very simple interface, I doubt they just forget make them clickable.

So my question is how can I published container?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up your container tag on your site and perhaps create some tags under the container
2. On the left hand side under Versions, click on Overview
3. You need to create a new version of your container each time you make changes in order to publish individual versions, so click Create Version at the top on the right of those 4 small icons (which I also thought were clickable).
4. Your new version will then be created and there'll be an Edit option on the page to rename your container. For example: Adwords Order Value Test
5. In this new container there's a button that says Preview. Clicking that will reveal a drop down menu with an option to Preview and Debug, which I strongly recommend. Placing an order (depending on the tag you're testing. In my case this is Adwords) on your site in another tab of the same browser will give you the option to see if these tags are firing in Google Tag Manager
6. Once you're satisfied that your tags are working, click the Publish button at the top of the page next to the Preview button. You have now published that version of the container and can revert back to any of the other previously published versions at a later stage if you feel you've made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Go to google tag manager in overview page after that you click create version option its there in right hand side.. after that you preview and publish your container...

that view edit symbol is used to we set another user only view this account and edit and manage this account...

It’s mandatory to create a new version before you preview a container or publish a container.

To create a new version of your container navigate to Versions section of GTM. Then use the Version button in the top right of the screen to create the new version.

Once you have a new version you can preview the version or you can publish it.

TIP: You can “roll back” your container tag to a previous version if there is ever a problem. Just click on the version that you want to “roll back” to and click the publish button in the top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to Google Tag Manager.
Select the account and the container within the account.
Click the Users link on the left side. A list of users will be displayed with the container permissions to the right.
Click the user name to update the account and container permissions. The icons pertain to the permissions allowed.